# Problem with displaying image of the Google map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I obtained coordinates via with expo-location, when obtaining the coordinates, I transfer it to the google api so that it gives me the image of the coordinate, but it doesn't display anything, it doesn't give me errors. I share the code for obtaining the map image and where I call it

MapPreview (getting the map image)

```
import {Image, View} from 'react-native';

import {URL_MAPS} from '../../utils/maps';
import {styles} from './style';

export default function MapPreview ({ children,location, style }) {
  const {lat, lgn } = location || {};
  const mapPreviewURL = URL_MAPS(lat, lgn);
  console.log(mapPreviewURL);
  return (
    <View style={{...styles.container, ...style}}>
      { location ? <Image style={styles.mapImage} source={{uri: mapPreviewURL}} /> : children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

getting URL API Google

```
export const API_KEY_MAPS = "";

export const URL_MAPS = (
  lat,
  lng,
  zoom = 14
) => `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${lat},${lng}&zoom=${zoom}&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C${lat},${lng}&key=${API_KEY_MAPS}`;
```

Where call it

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";

import { Boton, MapPreview, PhotoButton, PostHeader, TextBox } from "../../components";
import { Image, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Color from "../../constants/color";

const AddAdress = ( {navigation}) => {
  //useState
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [coords, setCoords] = useState(null);
  const [wCoords, setWCoords] = useState("Coordenadas: No hay coordenadas");

  //onChangeAdress
  const onChangeAddress = (text) => {
    setAddress(text);
  };

  //onChangeCity
  const onChangeCity = (text) => {
    setCity(text);
  };

  //onChangeCountry
  const onChangeCountry = (text) => {
    setCountry(text);
  };



  //onPressCamera
  const onPressCamera = () => {
    navigation.navigate('AFoto');
  }

  //onPressall
  const onPressall = () => {
    console.log("hola");
  };

  //onPressObtener
  const onPressObtener = async() => {
    const largeAddress = address + " " + city + " " + country;
    const geocodedLocation = await Location.geocodeAsync(largeAddress);
    const{latitude, longitude} = geocodedLocation[0];
    setCoords({lat:latitude, lgn: longitude}) ;
    onChangeCoords(coords);
    };

  //onChangeCoords
  const onChangeCoords = (coord) => {
    if (coord.lat == "" && coord.lgn == "")
    {
      console.log("No hay coordenadas");
    }
    else
    {
      const {lat, lgn} = coord;
      setWCoords("Coordenadas: Latitud: " + lat + " Longitud: " + lgn);
    }

  };

  //onPressReset
  const onPressReset = () => {
    setAddress("");
    setCity("");
    setCountry("");
    setCoords({lat: "", lgn: ""});
    setWCoords("");
  };


  const PhotoHead = require("../../../assets/Logo2.png");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={style.container}>
      <PhotoButton onPress= {onPressCamera} img= {PhotoHead}></PhotoButton>
      <PostHeader section="Per" />
      <View style={style.containerTextInput}>
        <Text style={style.font}>Agregar Direccion</Text>
        <TextBox
          placeholder="Direccion"
          value={address}
          onChangeText={onChangeAddress}
          alt={25}
          multiline={false}
          numLine={1}
        />
        <TextBox
          placeholder="Ciudad"
          value={city}
          onChangeText={onChangeCity}
          alt={25}
          multiline={false}
          numLine={1}
        />
        <TextBox
          placeholder="Pais"
          value={country}
          onChangeText={onChangeCountry}
          alt={25}
          multiline={false}
          numLine={1}
        />
        <View style = {style.containerMap}>
          <View style = {style.buttonMap}>
            <Boton title="Obtener" bkcolor={Color.primary} color={Color.white} onPress={onPressObtener} />
            <Boton title="Reset" bkcolor={Color.primary} color={Color.white} onPress={onPressReset} />
          </View>
          <View style = {style.map}>
            <MapPreview location={coords} style={style.mapReal} >
              <Text>Hola</Text>
            </MapPreview>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Text style={style.textAdress}>Direccion: {address}</Text>
        <Text style={style.textAdress}>Ciudad: {city}</Text>
        <Text style={style.textAdress}>Pais: {country}</Text>
        <Text style={style.textAdress}>{wCoords}</Text>
        <Boton title="Guardar" bkcolor={Color.primary} color={Color.white} onPress={onPressall} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default AddAdress;

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: Color.white,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: '100%',
  },
  containerTextInput: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: Color.primary,
    width: 404,
    height: "70%",
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  font: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: Color.white,
    marginHorizontal: 25,
    marginVertical: 10,
    alignSelf: 'baseline',
    marginLeft: 30,
  },

  containerMap: {
    width: '50%',
    height: '42%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  buttonMap: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

  map: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },

  mapReal:{
    flex:1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },

  textAdress:{
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',
    fontSize: 15,
    color: Color.white,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
});
```

I need you to explain to me what the error is and how to solve it Thank you

Comment: What you are trying to do ? Why you don‘t use MapView ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to obtain the coordinates for an address that contains the same address, city and country to project it onto the image provided by google map, it is assumed that through the google map API one can obtain that image

Comment: There is no need to deal with images, just use MapView and pass the coords